# Whatsapp sharing button with a countdown variable

Tags: php, html, countdown

Beginner in web coding, I have issue to code a sharing button that lead to whatsapp and that share a countdown.
I achieve it with static string but I can't load a variable in it...

Does someone know where my issue is please ?

```
   <script>
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Aug 20, 2022 12:00:00").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

// Get today's date and time
var now = new Date().getTime();
    
// Find the distance between now and the count down date
var distance = countDownDate - now;
    
// Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

var countdown_iam = days + "j " + hours + "h "
+ minutes + "m " + seconds + "s "

// Output the result in an element with id="countdown"
document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = countdown_iam;

// If the count down is over, write some text 
if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "SURPRISE!!!";
}
}, 1000);

function openWhatsApp() {
    //var countdown_whatsapp = "test";
    //alert(countdown_iam);
    window.open('whatsapp://send?text=' + countdown_iam);
    }

</script>

<h2> WhatsApp sharing Link </h2> 

<!-- create an image icon to open the WhatsApp onclick -->     
<img src="img/whatsapp.png" height="50" size="50" onclick="openWhatsApp()">
```

Thank's for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `countdown_iam` variable is created within a function and only exists within that function. So when the other function (`openWhatsApp`) tries to use the variable, it can't find it and the error occurs.

You want to access the countdown string from two different functions, so one option would be to create a new function that makes the countdown string and returns it. You can then call that function from both places. I've done that here:

```html
<script>

  function getCountdown() {
    var countdownDate = new Date("Aug 20, 2022 12:00:00").getTime();
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var distance = (countdownDate - now) / 1000;
    if (distance < 0) {
      return 'SURPRISE!!!';
    } else {
      var days = Math.floor(distance / (60 * 60 * 24));
      var hours = Math.floor((distance % (60 * 60 * 24)) / (60 * 60));
      var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (60 * 60)) / 60);
      var seconds = Math.floor(distance % 60);
      return days + "j " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
    }
  }

  function openWhatsApp() {
    alert('whatsapp://send?text=' + getCountdown());
  }

  setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = getCountdown();
  }, 1000);

</script>

<h2>WhatsApp Sharing Link</h2>
<p id="countdown"></p>
<p><img src="img/whatsapp.png" height="50" size="50" onclick="openWhatsApp()"></p>
```

Comment: Few hours passed to find why it wasn't working and you deal with my issue in a few minutes... A big thank's to you for the answer and a big thank's for the explanation. I hope I will not did the same mistake anymore.

Comment: You're very welcome, Ahriman! Glad I could help.